# Set custom cookies using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

is it possible to set a custom cookie through a Google Apps script gadget embedded in a Google site.  I've been trying using the HtmlService class (through document.coookie in a script from the html file) but it doesn't seem to generate the cookie.  I'm assuming this must be by design (i.e. Caja sanitisation).  Is there another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, by design, but you shouldn't need to; you can store information about the current user in UserProperties.

Comment: Deprecated. This class is deprecated and should not be used in new scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It's acctually possible if you use the iframe option just like this:

```
function doGet(e) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index.html")
                .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
// after that you may use (On "index.html"):
// document.cookie = "cookieName=1234";
```

best regards.

Comment: Using the 'document.cookie' did the job for me. N.B:. The 'IFRAME' is the default now & '.setSandboxMode' has no role now.